# Razor Page rendering page twice .net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

`Cars` razor page is invoking `OnGet()` twice on first load. When I click view button `View` razor page loads `OnGet(int id)` twice.
`Service.Submit` method is inserting two records instead of one.
Should it not call every page method only once ?

**cars.cshtml**

```html
@page 
@model IndexModel
@using MyApp.Models;

@{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Reference No</th>
                <th>Car Make</th>
                <th>Car Model</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (Car item in Model.CarList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ReferenceNo</td>
                    <td>@item.Make</td>
                    <td>@item.Model</td>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                    <td>@item.Year</td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-page="View" asp-route-id="@item.id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white">View</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**cars.cshtml.cs**

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    public List<Car> CarList = new List<Car>();

    public IndexModel(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void OnGet() // -----> this function is invoked twice.
    {
        try
        {
            CarList = _context.Car.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.sp_GetCars").ToList();                
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**view.cshtml.cs**

```cs
public class ViewModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;     
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

        public ViewModel(AppDbContext context, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
        {
            _context = context;
            _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;           
        }        
        public IActionResult OnGet(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                if (id != null) {
                    Service.Submit(id, _scopeFactory);  ------>Insert function is also invoked twice                   
                }
                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How familiar are you with how HTTP works?

Comment: look at  <a asp-page="View" asp-route-id="@item.id"  it's in a row, this will do for every row, read documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0, also you should connect to your backend via controller not your page

Comment: @Nonik The contents of a page has nothing to do with how many times that page is requested, and there are no controllers in [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: @GSerg so microsoft documentation is wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Comment: @Nonik No, it's just documentation for a different product, not [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: `on load and on page refresh.` on load will trigger `OnGet` method and refresh page will also trigger it, it's expected behavior. And `inserting two records` should be an issue but you didn't provide the code about how you send post request and how you deal with post request.

Comment: @TinyWang added the missing part

Comment: Use your browser tools (f12) Network tab to see what requests are being made.

Comment: @mxmissile no luck ! I can see only one query string being posted.

Comment: A few issues with your code. For starters, your View `OnGet` Service.Submit is being called on every OnGet no matter what, id will never be null because it is a  Value Type. Change it to `OnGet(int? id)`, this should prevent `Service.Submit` from being called on every request. Also, after `Service.Submit` you are redirecting back to Index, there is where I think you are confused on it being called twice.

Comment: What does view.cshtml look like and why are you redirecting back to Index on the Get? return RedirectToPage("Index");

Comment: @BradPatton There no html in view page. It's empty

Comment: @gorp88 then why have a view page? You should be posting back to the Index page or calling a web api. No point to have a razor page thats empty.

Comment: @BradPatton I tried that and did `OnPost` but it was making the list null and throwing exception. Basically, my requirement is to load the grid and then post it to the database using a razor pages. It working but inserting two records. Not sure how Razor page methods are different that the controllers.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to help troubleshoot, I write a form submit sample below and pls kindly let me know if it doesn't help, then I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please allow me write a sample here. I had a form in cshtml and provide `OnPost` method to handle it, then using Dependency Injection to inject service to handle the  database inserting method.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="ID" name="ID"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Title" name="Title"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit buttom" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr/>
</form>


public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger; 
    private readonly ICommonService _commonService;
    public IList<Movie> Movie { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, ICommonService commonService)
    {
        _logger = logger; 
        _commonService = commonService;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Movie = _commonService.getData();
    }

    public void OnPost(Movie mov) {
        var a = mov.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, added the form post tag and modified my button --- <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit" asp-route-id="@item.id" />